# Jenkins Multi Job configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have 2 jobs that run on a Jenkins slave -

```
1. AutoIT
2. MoveMouse
```

The first job has to run 4 times a day (eg. 8 AM, 12 PM, 6 PM, 9 PM)

**MouseMove** is also an **AutoIT** script that runs on the slave machine to keep it alive and prevent it from locking. **MouseMove** has to run continuously between these 4 jobs every 10 mins.
Also I have to make sure that both the jobs never overlap each other i.e. **MoveMouse** should run every 10 mins between two runs of **AutoIT**.

I have downloaded Multi Job Plugin and also created a multi job but I am not sure how can I achieve the above requirement.
I am able to trigger only one run of **MoveMouse** till now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could schedule AutoIT 4 times a day, and MouseMove every 10 minutes - and prevent them from running at the same time by using a plugin.  I suggest https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin